# ClassNotFoundException: org.terracotta.toolkit.internal.cache.ToolkitCacheInternal

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, terracotta

I have a question when I use spring4.2.6/hibernate5.1.0.Final. It comes when I use ehcache. The problem is a ClassNotFoundException:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.terracotta.toolkit.internal.cache.ToolkitCacheInternal
```

and my pom.xml is:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
  <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.39</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
  </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

ehcache.xml and spring-hibernate.xml are all configured.

Comment: It may be instructive to run "mvn dependency:tree" as I suspect that the jar containing terracotta's library is not present.

Comment: I have found the reason, and i will push it later

Comment: The error indicates that you are trying to cluster ehcache. Please provide the ehcache configuration to confirm.